# Video is not scaling up to cover player window

Tags: html, css, video, scale, video.js

I am playing around with the video.js and so far everything works as it should, with one exception. The videos won't scale up at all.

[image]

As you can see I'm getting black bars on the sides as well as on top.
Has anyone experienced something similar to this and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, and I did a reset on all the settings and tried again with the same result

Comment: Are you sure the video itself doesn't have the black bars top and bottom?

Comment: @misterben yes, that was actually the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that the video was encoded with the bars on the side, so this is not a video.js problem.
Thanks though!